# Cover UITableViewController view with contents of another nib

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that I need to cover with another nib in some situations

Whats a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the class UINavigationController.  It helps you manage a stack of view controllers, with only the top one visible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're attempting to do, you could use presentModalViewController:animated: to slide up a new view and cover your table. Then there is William's solution which would be to create a UINavigationController which will enable you to push and pop views into a stack.